# C#, ASP.NET MVC / MVC2: Url.Action - Link with specific parameters, leaving one out

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following code:

```
Url.Action("Index", "Home",  new {param1 = Model.Param1, param2 = Model.Param2} )
```

Now, if Param2 is NullOrEmpty I want to link using the following code:

```
Url.Action("Index", "Home",  new {param1 = Model.Param1} )
```

Is there an easier way to do this or will I need to do something like this:

```
string myLinkVal = (Model.Param2 == string.IsNullOrEmpty()) ? 
    Url.Action("Index", "Home",  new {param1 = Model.Param1} ) :
    Url.Action("Index", "Home",  new {param1 = Model.Param1, param2 = Model.Param2} );
```

EDIT:

Thank you for your answer. The Problem is, that I have the empty param in my link.

I have the following routes:

```
"/{param1}/{param2}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
...
"/{param1}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

When Param2 is empty I want to use the other route (the one without param2).

Currently I can only archieve this by using

```
new {param1 = Model.Param1, param2 = Model.Param2}
```

or

```
new {param1 = Model.Param1}
```

Then the correct route is picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran a couple quick test, and assuming Model.Param2 is a string (which it looks like it is by your example code), then MVC already handles this.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Click Me", "TestAction", new { id = 5, name="" })%>
<%= Html.ActionLink("Click Me", "TestAction", new { id = 5 })%>
```

Both of the above result in the same URL being rendered.

For completeness, here is what my action method looks like (at least the signature):

```
public ActionResult TestAction(int id, string name)  {...}
```

HTH,
Brian

Comment: thank you for your answer. My Problem is that this way I have the empty parameter in my url. I have edited my original post. Thank you very much for your help so far!

Comment: Given your updated information, you can probably only achieve what you want using named routes.  Here's a link that describes how they work: http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/named-routes-aspnet-mvc.  Actually, you can probably get away with not using named routes if you move param2 to the end of your route template, not sure if that's an option though.

Comment: Is there also an Url.Action() like method to direct select the route to use?

Comment: You will want to use Url.RouteUrl()

Answer (score 0):

You could try constructing your object parameter list in your controller, and then pass that as part of the viewModel

```
Url.Action("Index", "Home",  Model.ParamList);
```

Where ParamList is just an object. It wouldn't reduce your if/else logic any, but it would remove said logic from your View.

Comment: How can I construct this ParamList at the controller? something like ParamList = new object() {param1 = Model.Param1, param2 = Model.Param2}; will not work. What type is this object?

Comment: You should be able to do `var list = new { param1 = "", param2 = "" };` and it will get past along